# Creating tabbed document interfaces in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I am trying to write a program that will use a tabbed document interface (TDI) like seen in Notepad++ or most web browsers. I know how to build GUIs using Qt Designer, and code in Qt C++ (after a few days of playing around).

I have created an example of what each page widget will look like using Designer, and now I want to add the ability to create and testroy tabs at runtime, each containing a unique instance of the page widget. However, I have no idea how to do this without adding a class that extends QWidget, and building the page widget with code. I could go down this route, but I'm sure there must be a better way of creating a TDI; but I can't find any tutorials or examples of how to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For creating tab interfaces you should look into [QTabWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtabwidget.html).

It is a container widget included in Qt Designer which automatically handles operations on tabs. It has several build in methods for manipulating its tabs and theirs contents.

Each page of [QTabWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtabwidget.html) is handled separately and can have different layouts and functionality.

If you want to include several different objects to one page assign a layout to it and then assign the objects to the layout.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't think I made myself clear: I am already using a QTabWidget, but I don't know to create tabs at runtime, each with a different instance of the same group of widgets. Currently, my program looks like this: [link](http://puu.sh/4ujjL.png), where the highlighted area is a QWidget containing everthing that should be on all tabs created.

Comment: @user2652805 What do you mean by "create tabs an runtime"? Should new tabs be added when some button is clicked? Should some number of tabs be already there when you're starting the program? I do not understand that bit. EDIT: from what it looks like from the image you posted new tabs should be created on some kind of event or signal, don't they?

Comment: Yes, the program I am making is an IRC client, where each tab is a separate channel. Sorry, I'm really bad at explaining things :(

Comment: In that case you would need to create a new tab and then create a method, say `populateLayout()` which would fill the desired layout with widgets and then add this layout to a new page of `QTabWidget`. Extending the QWidget class would really be easier.